# Is there a Yarn equivalent for "npm dedupe"?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

Just tried out Yarn and indeed it's mega-fast. After running `yarn` in the console with a loaded `package.json`, it installed everything. I then ran `npm dedupe` expecting nothing much to happen since Yarn is so optimized, but it removed a *ton* of stuff. Is there some Yarn equivalent to `npm dedupe`?

**Addition:**

As noted in my comment below, I thought perhaps `yarn install --flat` might be an `npm dedupe` equivalent as the [Yarn documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/installing-dependencies#toc-installing-options) describes it as "installing one and only one version of a package". So I played around with `--flat` and there's a couple things to note:

1. It will prompt you to choose what version of a package to install when the tree results in requests for more than one version. I could imagine this being one hell of a task for larger projects. I just picked the latest version for each package I was prompted for and as you can imagine, trying to run the app resulted in `cannot find module` errors.
2. I ran `npm dedupe` *after* doing a `yarn install --flat` and it *still* resulted in a ton of removals. This was a surprise to me.

So I'm taking it that `npm dedupe` is doing some other magic under the hood and I'm just naive about processes that I need not be concerned with. Perhaps it's just best to leave the tree alone and forget about `--flat` and `dedupe` altogether.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible since it would result in a non deterministic tree.

Comment: @FelixKling Oops! Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer So with Yarn, does dedupe become irrelevant?

Comment: Perhaps what I was looking for was `yarn install --flat`? According to the [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/installing-dependencies), the `--flat` option installs "one and only one version of a package".

Comment: Looks like the --flat option installs everything in the same level. Which is probably for usage with non module based environments ( a browser ), sorry I don't have a better answer...

Comment: Yarn install does dedupe automatically. `npm dedupe` does the same and prunes the packages that are not relevant. `--flat` forces you to choose which version each package should resolve to for everything, leaving only a single package.

Comment: @SteveBuzonas you should add that as an answer (with references)!

Comment: @mikemaccana I had the same thought, but left it as a comment because at the time I didn't want to find references. Completely forgot about coming back to it.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like even now Yarn doesn't do the greatest job of minimizing duplicate dependencies. Running `yarn --flat` forces there to be only one version of a dependency even when they may not be compatible, so that's not ideal. You can use the [`yarn-deduplicate`](https://github.com/atlassian/yarn-deduplicate) package to minimize the number of duplicates, while still allowing some in cases where there are not overlapping requirements. `yarn-deduplicate` also has a `--fail` option which will return a non-zero (failing) status. This can be useful to run on CI to ensure that anybody who modifies dependencies doesn't introduce new duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

`npx yarn-dedupe` does a very good job

Answer (score -1):

Quoted from the Yarn docs:

> The dedupe command isn’t necessary. `yarn install` will already dedupe.

https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/dedupe/

Comment: `yarn install` does not appear to dedupe. That is, not in all cases. So there is either a bug in `yarn install` or it simply does not work. I ran `yarn install` followed by `yarn check` and received this message: `warning "chokidar#fsevents#node-pre-gyp@^0.10.0" could be deduped from "0.10.3" to "node-pre-gyp@0.10.3"`

Comment: You should report that behaviour then since the docs clearly state that dedupe is not needed.